# knitr: Document does not change anymore

Tags: r, knitr

I have a .Rnw document in which I include childs. The childs produce tables via the 'latex' command of the Hmisc library in R.

When I make changes in the child documents, these changes do not anymore change the pdf document. My first guess was to use the chunk option 'eval=TRUE', but this does not change anything. Then, I saw, that the tables are actually saved to a .tex file with same name as the .Rnw document. I deleted this file and after compilation with knitr I got an error:

Error: Latexmk: Could not find file documentname.tex.

I assume, this is not the way to do it. Now I am out of ideas what to do. I appreciate some help on my problem.

Best
Simon

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Allright, when trying to construct a simple example, I actually found out, that neither the packages I included nor the nesting of child documents interfere with the compilation via knitr. The reason was a simple error in the low-level .Rnw document, where a Hmisc latex table had a label, that missed a closing speech mark.

This causes then the output pdf not to change - I assume, that in this case the already constructed .tex file is included instead of letting knitr recompile the .Rnw documents and this hasn't changed since the last compilation?

What I wonder about is the different format of the landscape ctable in the document. Using a simple knitr document just with \documentclass{article} produces well placed tables. In my document using a template for the JFE, I get a table that extends over the whole page and even in footnotesize it is far away from the great appearance in the simple document. There is only a margin of less than half a cm on the right and the left. Page size is the same: both US letter... Can I probably control that via knitr or only via resizebox?